# Replace any number that starts with a certain letter

Tags: javascript, regex

Little regex help? I can't tell why this isn't matching. I was able to find things contained by `[` `]` with a similar pattern...

I'd like to match and have the option to replace all strings that start with `s` and all the digits touching them, until interrupted by anything besides 0-9.

I did try to figure this out :)

Thought I was matching:

- Anything that starts with space s: `/\ s` (escaping the space)
- Then grabbing all digits in a greedy way: `\d+?`
- Do it globally: `/g`

Missing something though. Fiddle and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SimpleAsCouldBe/eLbcbr7z/1/

```
stringBlob = "because sally said so s324 * s42"
// Should replace `s324` and `s42`

console.log('original: ', stringBlob);

replaced = stringBlob.replace(
    /\ s(\d+?)/g,

    // also tried:
    // /\ s\d+/g,
    // /\ s(.+?) /g,
    // /\ s(.+) /g,

    function(tokenWithDelimeter, token) {
        console.log(token);
        return "REDACTED";
    }
);

console.log('replaced: ', replaced);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of: `/\ s(\d+?)/g` you can use:

```
/\bs\d+\b/g
```

i.e. surrounded by word boundaries.

#### [Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbcbr7z/2/)

Your regex `\ s\d+?` will match a space followed by letter `s` and then 1 or more digits (non-greedy). That will just make  `s3` in first instance instead of `s324`.

Comment: I see. So this will also work: `/\ s\d+/g`, but your solution is nicer because it uses idiomatic `\b` behavior and I don't have to re-introduce the blank space after replacement. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes matching space is problematic in the sense it needs to be used in replacement string also.

Comment: I actually ended up using `/\bf(\d+)\b/g`, because it gives me both the target token and the token with delimiters in the replace function. I see that the docs call this "capturing" the match but don't understand it fully.

Comment: Yes it is indeed called matching group. It is used when you need a backreference to it in replacement string OR in the pattern itself.